# How many word can we make with infinited times of $B$, $D$ $M$ and only one $O$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

> In a case, we have infinite times of the letter B, D, M and only one O. How many different word containing those letter can we make (*can be meaningless in this term*) ?

Comment: If the words can be meaningless and infinite copies of letters are available, we can make infinitely many strings of letters and call them words.

Comment: If you mean making words with length k, I answered

Comment: Sorry. It is my fault. The word should be consisted of only 4 letters and that can be constructed in many ways and we can surely approach with the permutation process. No matter whatever the word means. I beg your pardon and I didn't understand the length of the word 'k'.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy Oh... k is just any variable :D no problem man gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have infinite letters of at least 2 types you can make infinite words.
Example:

B, BD, BBD, BBBD, ...

If you mean words with length n:

Denote the ways to make a word with infinite B,D,M and length k by G(k).Then the answer you need is G(n) + n * G(n-1).

To find G(n), let's say the word is _ _ _ ... _ _ _. Then each blank can be B, D or M so G(n) = 3^n

Therefore **You can make 3^n + n * 3^(n-1) words with length n with infinite B, D and M and 1 O**